# MetroHash has different hashing than MurmurHash3 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, hash, buffer, murmurhash

So in when i use in Javascript  murmurhash-native/stream like so:

```
const murmur = require("murmurhash-native/stream");



const hash = murmur.createHash("murmurhash128");
hash.update('hash').digest('hex');


console.log(hash.digest("hex"));
```

the console.log result is:

```
4ab2e1e022f63e2e9add75dfcea2dede
```

However, using MetroHash in Python with the following setup:

```
import metrohash



m = metrohash.MetroHash128(0)
m.update("hash")

print(m.hexdigest())
```

i get on the otherhand from the print the value

```
e8a8b5ad0ae42fb46ab073e8bd98479a
```

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I understood metrohash.MetroHash128 is used for incremental hashing, which is exactly what im looking for in Python, but somehow the result values are for the same input different.

Ive checked if there is any other library that supports incremental hashing in Python, but it seems MetroHash is so far the only one?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Metrohash and murmur hash are two different hash functions.

Comment: Really? I thought MetroHash is based on MurmurHash. I've tried mmh3 as well, which should be a wrapper around MurmurHash3, however, i don't get the same result. Like i use the above example but with mmh3.hash for example or mmh3.hash128 i get also totally different results for the hash.. kinda lost why.